# garbage strings printed from a const char pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, constants

I'm trying to print out slected strings from a const char pointer array but the text displayed is absolutely garbage. I am not sure what went wrong. I condensed the code down for easy read below:

```
#pragma once
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define HAND_CARDS 5 /* maximum number of cards any particular Hand */

typedef struct card {
    int suit;
    int face;
} Card;

typedef struct hand {
    struct card pHand[5];
    int hQuality;
} Hand;

void print_pHand(struct hand player, const char* suit[], const char* face[]);


int main(void)
{
    /* initialize memory arrays of suit and face, to be referenced through out the game */
    const char *suit[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    const char *face[13] = {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
                            "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    int deck[4][13] = { 0 };
    Hand pHuman = { 0 };

    print_pHand(pHuman, suit, face);
    return 0;
}

void print_pHand(struct hand player, const char* suit[], const char* face[])
{
    int f = 0, s = 0, i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < HAND_CARDS; ++i) {
        s = player.pHand[i].suit;
        f = player.pHand[i].face;
        printf("[%s : %s]\t", suit[s], face[f]);
    }
}
```

I changed the printf() part and it still produced the same problem.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x79B81F4C (ucrtbased.dll) in PA7.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xF485A8D3. occurred
```

[image]

Seems like there is memory access problem but I am not sure how to fix it.

Note: Assuming the cards have already been dealt randomly to each player, although I might have missed some important part. So for the full code, please look at my github here:

https://github.com/karln-create/PA7-5CDPoker

Comment: @karln-createt  pHuman is initialized with zeroes.

Comment: `"[%5s : %-8s%c"` need 3 args not 2

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow but the struct's internal parameters are integers. So It shouldn't matter whether are initialized to zero or not right? Plus I used indices to locate the array's block, from which the string is stored.

Comment: @karln-create I mean that the call does not make great sense. Also in the printf call you are using an incorrect number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks I changed the printf part.

Comment: Other than the problem with the `printf` format that was already mentioned, I don't see any reason for the program to fail, and indeed, it runs fine for me.  Does *the code you've actually presented* (+ the format correction) in fact fail for you?  My only guess then would be that you are compiling it inappropriately, such as with a C++ compiler (though I don't know what specifically about the code might be broken in C++).

Comment: Thank you for checking, the program does compile successfully. However, it seems somewhere along the line, data is corrupted when the the program retrieves data stored in the const char arrays (suit and face, particularly the face array). I used both VScode and VS2019. The program is being written and debugged primarily in VS2019, although I also use VSCode with GCC side by side to work on small snippets of code.

Comment: With your code, there is not any garbage string when i run by compiler online. l am worry about  this part `Note: Assuming the cards have already been dealt randomly to each player, although I might have missed some important part`.  OT, the sreenshot is not like the result of the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry, the program is larger. I didn't want to throw out a wall of code, so I tried to slim down to the part I think is the most relevant and more likely to be the source of the problem. The full code is accessible through my github. Please take a look and see if you could replicate the same problem.

Comment: This is where a Minimal Complete Verfiable Example comes into play.  Cut it down, but verify that the cut-down version exhibits the behavior in question.  If it doesn't, that should give you a hint as to where the problem actually lies.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.  The posted code causes the compiler to output 3 warnings, Those warnings need to be corrected.

Comment: I went to your gethub listings, downloaded the whole project, then tried to compile each file.   NONE of the C files compiled.

Comment: I used the basic ```-Wall -g -c``` so maybe that's why it didn't throw up the important flags. I'm breaking down the code and recompiling in gcc again.

Comment: Thanks, I got everything compiled in the simplified version. Now I just need to figure out what went wrong with the main project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your code,

```
printf("[%5s : %-8s%c", suit[s], face[f]);
```

is passing insufficient amount of arguments to `printf()`. As there are three `'%'` in your call, `printf()` expects another three arguments, not two. However, since `printf()` is implemented as a variadic function, it had no idea how many arguments you actually passed to it, so it managed to access some memory where your non-existent third argument would have occupied, causing the error.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.